# Admin page on django is broken

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-admin, login-page

I've set up a django project with an admin page.  It worked perfectly for the first couple weeks of development, didn't use the admin page for a while, and when I came back to it, the admin page was broken.  No matter what I do, it won't allow me to log in.

After entering username and PW, the admin page always says:

> Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields are case-sensitive.

I've checked the DB: the superuser exists and has is_active, is_superuser, and is_staff all True. I've used the shell to make sure the password is correct.  I've flushed, deleted, and re-created the database multiple times to make sure there's no mistake.  I've also doublechecked the middleware, urls, INSTALLED_APPS, etc to make sure they're all set up properly.

As far as I can tell, the admin pages work perfectly except that they never let anyone log in.

Any ideas what's going on here, or other methods for trying to debug?  I'm really baffled by this bug.

PS: In case it matters, I'm using South for DB migrations, django-social-auth for FB logins, and separate local_settings.py for production and development (I've checked them both -- the conflict isn't there.)

Comment: What happens if you create your own login page using the auth.views.login() view?

Comment: Looks like pretty much the same issue: "Your username and password didn't match. Please try again."

Comment: To get the django-social-auth working for FB logins, did you modify any of the code that could be changing the way the system runs authenticate() and login()? Also, in the weeks of development, have you removed and recreated the project, such that settings.py's SECRET_KEY = '...' has changed? I think this key is used to decrypt the password, but I'm not positive.

Comment: Not that I know of. I added a view and a model, plus some entries in settings.py, but nothing else that I can remember.

Comment: On SECRET_KEY... Yes, I switched repos, and when I did, I ran django-admin startproject again.  So my PWs are hashed differently now.  But I would have thought that creating a new superuser and/or completely flushing and re-creating the DB would solve that problem.  BTW, I'm using sqlite in development, in case that's important.

Comment: maybe this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55546476/6131019

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This problem may be related to the Authentication Backends.
Please check your settings files for the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS parameter.

Try the following value:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    ('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'),
)
```

More information on the
[Official Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#specifying-authentication-backends)

Comment: Bingo.  That was the problem -- when I added django-social-auth, it included a whole list of authentication backends, including django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend.  I commented out all the rows I didn't plan to use, without noticing that I was commenting out that one as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try this; in tests.py:

```
from django.contrib import auth

class AuthTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.u = User.objects.create_user('test@dom.com', 'test@dom.com', 'pass')
        self.u.is_staff = True
        self.u.is_superuser = True
        self.u.is_active = True
        self.u.save()

    def testLogin(self):
        self.client.login(username='test@dom.com', password='pass')
```

Then run the test with `python manage.py test <your_app_name>.AuthTestCase`. If this passes, the system is working, maybe look at the username and password to make sure they are acceptable.

Comment: The test works -- returns OK.  But the login on the site still doesn't work.  I've checked the password in the shell, using check_password, and it returns True.  Here's something even stranger: if I enter my email address instead of the superuser name, I get "Your e-mail address is not your username. Try 'agong' instead."  So it's clearly able to access the record in the DB -- it just won't let me log in.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS flag on settings file was not the problem for me. Using Django Rest Framework somehow i had modified the password without calling set_password therefore bypassing hashing the password. That's why it was showing the invalid login.

I was able to detect the issue by running simple test in order to test the user creation by a similar test:

```
from django.test import TestCase

from django.contrib import auth
from .models import *

class AuthTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.u = UserProfile.objects.create_user('test@dom.com', 'iamtest', 'pass')
        self.u.is_staff = True
        self.u.is_superuser = True
        self.u.is_active = True
        self.u.save()

    def testLogin(self):
        self.client.login(username='test@dom.com', password='pass')
```

It is also worth mentioning that I was creating a custom user named UserProfile

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a custom user model and forgot add it in `settings.py`? That is what just happened to me.

```
# Substituting a custom User model

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "app_custom_auth.User"
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to delete the `db.sqlite3` and migrate again (`python manage.py migrate`) then do:

```py
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

to create the account again.

Comment: This temporarily fixed my problem. Is there a way to do this without deleting db.sqlite3 because I lose all the user accounts?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

- Enter your mysql (or other database console)
- USE YourDATABASE;
- SELECT * from auth_user;
- watch is_staff and is_superuser item
- UPDATE auth_user SET is_staff = "1" where username = "root";

Then you can login again!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is :

```
def create_superuser(self, username, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
    user = self.create_user(username, email, password=password, is_staff=True, **extra_fields)
    user.is_active = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

`is_active` and `is_staff` must be `True` to log in Django Admin so in these cases below, you can log in Django Admin:

```
is_active   ✅
is_staff    ✅
is_superusr
```

```
is_active   ✅
is_staff    ✅
is_superusr ✅
```

In addition, even if `is_superusr` is `True`, you cannot log in Django Admin in these cases below because making `is_superusr` `True` gives the user all permissions except logging in Django Admin:

```
is_active
is_staff    ✅
is_superusr ✅
```

```
is_active   ✅
is_staff
is_superusr ✅
```

```
is_active
is_staff
is_superusr ✅
```

Answer (score 0):

Another issue that can cause this is **custom middleware**, as it can interfere with the request/response cycle. This interference might not always throw explicit errors but can prevent processes like authentication from completing successfully.

Try disabling any custom middleware in `settings.py` and see if that solves your problem.

For example, converting the default Django WSGIRequest to a DRF 'Request' object has side effects that can cause standard Django views (including Django Admin) to have issues. For example, the below `custom_logging_middleware.py` would cause issues logging into Django Admin:

```
from rest_framework.request import Request
import logging


class RequestLoggingMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        start_time = time.time()
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

        # Wrap the original request with DRF's Request, since the standard Django WSGIRequest doesn't have a .data attribute
        drf_request = Request(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue so problem was that I don't want to use username instead of username I wanted to use Email so in settings I have added

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['authentication.views.EmailBackend']
```

So Might be you are using username instead of that you can try with email.

For me It worked.