# Tweeter Oauth:You are authenticated as XXX, but are not authorized to access this page. Would you like to login to a different account?

Tags: django, oauth, django-allauth

I have created just a simple django app to login using tweeter, but when i try to login from my app I get this message
"You are authenticated as xxx, but are not authorized to access this page. Would you like to login to a different account?"

[image: Screenshot showing message]

I have tried to login with account I used to create the app and different account, but the result is the same. What could be the solution to this?

I am using django and django-allauth library

Answer (score 3):

To access the Django admin, the user needs `is_staff=True`. If you log into the admin with a superuser, you can edit your `testmyap` user and set the flag.

If you have not yet created a superuser, you can create one with:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Comment: You are absolutely right @Alasdair, I used admin for my callback url, and user testmyap was no and admin  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

On the terminal type:

```
$ python manage.py shell
$ from django.contrib.auth.models import User
$ u = User.objects.get(username='testmyapp')
$ u.is_superuser = True
$ u.save()
$ quit()
$ python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'users.User'

Answer (score 1):

If using a custom user model (which the Django docs recommend), Django will throw an error: "AttributeError: Manager isn't available...", which is the problem @elizandro-sparcbr had in 2021.

The steps are a bit different than the answer by @Paolo. When I ran into the "Manager isn't available" problem, the steps below worked for me in Feb 2022, on Django 3.2.

**settings.py**

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
```

(Or if using [cookiecutter](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.2/), then in settings folder, modify base.py as above.)

In the terminal:

```
$ python manage.py shell
$ from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
$ User = get_user_model()
$ u = User.objects.get(username='testmyap')
$ u.is_staff = True  # required to access admin panel
$ u.is_superuser = True  # optional
$ u.save()
$ quit()
```

The key steps that are different are the 2nd and 3rd lines above.

For more background on why this is required and what these steps are doing, see:

- [Django ticket #21616](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21616) about "Manager isn't available."
- Django docs for "[Customizing authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/)."
- Will Vincent's post "[Django Best Practices: Referencing the User Model](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-best-practices-referencing-user-model)."

Answer (score 0):

Check that the user has the is_staff attribute set to 1