# Can't login with super user created account in Python 3.8

Tags: python, django

Before i go forward, I know this is a commonly asked question but I have searched the top questions related to this, and none of it seems to be helping..

Following: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial02/

What I have done:

```
py manage.py createsuperuser
```

Created user

I have confirmed the user is a superuser with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
active_staff = User.objects.filter(is_active=True, is_staff=True)
```

This will then list the super users

<strike>Although, when I do something like:</strike>

u = User(username="admin")
u.is_staff
 False
u.is_superuser
 False

Why is this?

I also then manually set to true, `save()`, then check, and it's now True.  Try to log in, doesn't work.  restart shell and check, it's back to false.

I tried the accepted answer here: [Can't login to django admin after creating a super user with a custom user model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971928/cant-login-to-django-admin-after-creating-a-super-user-with-a-custom-user-model)

This: [Admin page on django is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844536/admin-page-on-django-is-broken)

None have helped.

If there is anything i need to copy/paste from my Djnago app to help, pleaes let me know.  I am new with Python and Django so I'm not exactly sure what to add to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am unsure how this is possible..

I have been creating the app in the directory d/programming/mysite with success... creating files, migrations etc.

I just checked and the app within the project is really in d/programming/django/mysite... i went ahead and created a user from there and it worked.

I'm a bit confused on how this is happening but I'm sure I'm wrong somehow and somewherea

Answer (score 2):

for having a superuser you only have to use manage.py createsuperuser command,and by using this command,you are doing:

```
    User(is_superuser=True,**kwargs)
```

so can you explain that what error exactly you see when you wanna login to admin panel?

Comment: Error:Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields are case-sensitive. ... This is just the notice.  there are no other errors to my knowledge in the console.  Just shows the GET and POST

Answer (score 1):

```
u = User(username="admin")
```

This is just initializing a new User Object and not querying the database. It will always return False for is_staff and superuser, as False if their default Value. Try querying the database using -

```
u = User.objects.get(username="admin")
```

to check the values of the flags.

Comment: Oh okay well that makes sense now why is was false.  I just checked manually and everything is True for superuser and staff