# Create a custom superuser django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a custom user model but when I create a superuser with "python manage.py createsuperuser" and try to login from the django admin, I get this message:

> Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.

username and password are correct.

and this is my models:

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, password, **extra_fields):
        user = self.model(username=username)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)
    
        return self.create_user(username, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=10,unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []


    publisher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try including `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` in the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`  parameter. Similar question is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844536/admin-page-on-django-is-broken).

Answer (score 1):

You must include your `extra_fields` when creating your user.
So your third line must be like below:

```
user = self.model(username=username, **extra_fields)
```